# PHP writes content to a javascript script

Tags: php

**How does php write the following content into a javascript script?**

**PHP:**

```
$info = [
    'version' => '1.1.0',
    'url' => 'http://www.xx.com/text?_id='.'id'
];
file_put_contents('/Users/nxy/Desktop/test.js', 'var id = util.getCookie('id'); module.exports = '. json_encode($info));
```

**test.js**

```
var id = util.getCookie('id');
module.exports = {
    version: "1.0.0",
    siteroot: "http://www.xx.com/text?_id=" + id,
};
```

Comment: Not with `file_put_contents()` as that will overwrite the file not add to it, unless you create the whole file

Comment: @RiggsFolly Need to create the entire file.

Comment: Ok, so not sure what your problem is then. Can you expand on the issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to create <test.js>  with php

Comment: One issue is that you can't use single quotes inside single quotes without escaping them. The current code should throw a parse error. Easiest would be to use double quotes inside the string. Change `util.getCookie('id')` to `util.getCookie("id")`.

Comment: You also can't get `"http://www.xx.com/text?_id=" + id,` from `json_encode()` since it's not valid json.

Comment: Since there's no variables being added or anything, why don't you just create the JS file manually and write the contents into it directly? Why go through PHP at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to make this nice and simple like this

```
$str = '
var id = util.getCookie("id");
module.exports = {
    version: "1.1.0",
    siteroot: "http://www.xx.com/text?_id=" + id,
};
';

file_put_contents('/Users/nxy/Desktop/test.js', $str);
```

And if its to change the version number then for example

```
$vers = '1.2.1';

$str = '
var id = util.getCookie("id");
module.exports = {
    version: "' . $vers . '",
    siteroot: "http://www.xx.com/text?_id=" + id,
};
';
```

Comment: Then the question comes, why even do it using PHP instead of just adding that to the correct file from the start?

Comment: That is a very good point @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am assuming OP is changing the version number

Comment: Well, I got it wrong at first, it should be written in a string. Instead of using json